# Why doesn't the SourceUpdated event trigger for my Image Control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I have an image control on a Window in my WPF project

XAML:

```
<Image 
  Source="{Binding NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
  Binding.SourceUpdated="bgMovie_SourceUpdated" 
  Binding.TargetUpdated="bgMovie_TargetUpdated" />
```

In code I am changing the source of the image

C#:

```
myImage = new BitmapImage();
myImage.BeginInit();
myImage.UriSource = new Uri(path);
myImage.EndInit();
this.bgMovie.Source = myImage;
```

But the bgMovie_SourceUpdated event is never triggered.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: protip:  Cut out the nonsense and fit everything on screen to increase the likelihood of someone answering your question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By assiging a value directly to the `Source` property, you're "unbinding" it... Your `Image` control is not databound anymore, it just has a local value.

In 4.0 you could use the `SetCurrentValue` method:

```
this.bgMovie.SetCurrentValue(Image.SourceProperty, myImage);
```

Unfortunately this method isn't available in 3.5, and there is no easy alternative...

Anyway, what are you trying to do exactly ? What is the point of binding the `Source` property if you're setting it manually anyway ? If you want to detect when the `Source` property changes, you can use the `DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged` method:

```
var prop = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Image.SourceProperty, typeof(Image));
prop.AddValueChanged(this.bgMovie, SourceChangedHandler);
...

void SourceChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: SetCurrentValue - nice - I wasn't aware of this in my rookie campaign into 4.0...

Comment: So, I upgraded my project to 4.0 last night and used SetCurrentValue, but it still won't trigger the SourceUpdated event.  I removed all the binding code in the XAML file and pointed the control's SourceUpdated event at the correct function.  Am I still missing something?

Comment: The "Source" word in the SourceUpdated event has nothing to do with the image source, it refers to the source of the binding. SourceUpdated will be triggered if the control updates the source of the binding, which will never happen with your code. But the TargetUpdated event should be triggered...

Answer (score 5):

By hard-coding the Source in the code, you are breaking the Binding in your XAML.

Instead of doing that, bind to a property that you set using (most of) the same code above.  Here's one way to do that.

XAML:

```
<Image Name="bgMovie" 
       Source="{Binding MovieImageSource, 
                        NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                        NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
       Binding.SourceUpdated="bgMovie_SourceUpdated" 
       Binding.TargetUpdated="bgMovie_TargetUpdated" />
```

C#:

```
    public ImageSource MovieImageSource
    {
        get { return mMovieImageSource; }
        // Set property sets the property and implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        set { SetProperty("MovieImageSource", ref mMovieImageSource, value); }
    }

   void SetMovieSource(string path)
   {
        myImage = new BitmapImage();
        myImage.BeginInit();
        myImage.UriSource = new Uri(path);
        myImage.EndInit();
        this.MovieImageSource = myImage;
   }
```